# Text search in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to do something that should be easy, but I think I'm misunderstanding the documentation. In Meteor I'm searching for a particular text string and if it's found then return that document.

So the collection might have the following structure:

```
{ 
  ...
  DONATE: "15,16,17",
  Amount: "3000,2000,1000",
  Address: "123 Main Street",
  ...
}
```

Then, if the DONATE string contains "15", for example, then return that document. Something like:

```
Demographic.findOne({ DONATE: { text: "15"}});
```

I've read [this](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Fulltext_search), but I'm not sure if it's is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a `$regex` operator

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

```
Demographic.findOne({ DONATE: { $regex: /15/ } });
```

If it finds a match, it will return a mongo object like this

```
{"_id": ObjectId("jsdkflsdjfklsdfjklsdf", "DONATE": "15,16,16")}
```

Otherwise it will return `null`

Tested it out in my console and it works!

Comment: Yes, that works. Just so anyone else my have the same situation, if you've got the value "15" in a variable named 'donate' for example (from a Session or wherever), then drop the slashes: Demographic.find({ DONATE: { $regex: donate } });